Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin \left( \frac{\sin \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^\alpha}} \right)$
I'm trying to figure out for which real values of $\alpha$ does this sum converges:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \left( \frac{\sin\left(\,{\sqrt{n}}\,\right)}{\sqrt{n^\alpha}} \right)
\end{equation}

I initially thought we could apply Dirihlet test for the inner function and then direct comparison test, but I realized that we cannot easily proof
$\ \sum \sin\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$ convergence.
Besides, the $\sin\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$ function takes negative values at some $n$, the direct comparison test cannot be applied here as well.

So now I'm stuck on that problem.

The terms of the series are not always positive, so comparison tests cannot be applied here.

Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118998/convergence-of-sum-frac-sin-sqrtnna
